# RequireJS Dependent Paths

Tags: requirejs

I've just started using RequireJS. I'm setting up a few path aliases to save me from having to specify the version number on my dependencies but it seems I can't combine a path alias with a directory alias. For example:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/js/app", // by default load any module IDs from js/app

    paths: {
        "libs": "/some/path/to/libs",
        "jquery": "libs/jquery-1.9.0" // loads from /some/path/to/libs/jquery-1.9.0.js
    }
});

require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $("#foo").html("bar");
});
```

RequireJS attempts to load jquery from `/js/app/libs/jquery-1.9.0.js`

Is this possible or would I need to define each js file path separately (if I didn't want to remove the version number)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

To quote James Burke's answer to a similar question in this [ticket](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/494):

> Paths are not additive -- the property name for a path entry is a
>   module ID and the value is a path that is not computed from other
>   values.

I think you do have to define each js file path separately, I can't think of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine however `require(["libs/jquery"]` should be changed to `require(["jquery"]` since you've defined that alias in your config.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: What error are you getting?  And is "/some/path/to/libs" relative to your baseUrl?

Comment: 404 as RequireJS attempts to load `/js/app/libs/jquery-1.9.0.js`. No `/some/path/to/libs` is not a relative path. That said, it doesn't work with relative paths either e.g. ../some/path/to/libs also doesn't work.

Comment: Does it try to load from the same path when using the relative path `../some/path/to/libs`?  It should then try and load from `js/some/path/to/libs/jquery-1.9.0.js`

Couple other things: According to the spec, I believe you should be using `define(['jquery'], function...` instead of `require(['jquery...`.  Also, RequireJS [recommends](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) you keep the version number in a different file (like a package.json) to minimize configuration.

Comment: I've now read through the full RequireJS docs and it does not mention anywhere that you can use paths in this way. Also, I was not defining a module, this code was executed in my `main.js`.